# What is the formula for finding the summation of an exponential function?

Tags: calculus, exponential-sum

I am having a hard time researching how to handle summations of functions with exponential growth or decay. I know that simple summations can be calculated as follows:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

How do you approach problems of exponential decay or growth? Consider the following example:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{50} e^{-0.123(n)}$$

Comment: Do you know how to find the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: @sharding4 No I don't but I am assuming that is the terminology I should be trying to use when I am researching. I am going to go ahead and research that now. This was one of those subjects for me where I ask myself "how do i even google this?"

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^N r^n = \frac{r^{N+1} - 1}{r-1}$ is the basic formula.

Comment: @Malcom from my limited understanding of the subject matter. r would be a constant, is that correct?

Comment: @pyRabbit yes a constant. In your example $r =\mathrm e^{-0.123}$ but you need to account for the fact that you start at $n=1$ not $n=0$

Comment: @DanRobertson Thank you very much. I think this is more than enough to get me started. I appreciate your help as well Malcom and sharding4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can recognize your sum as a geometric sum which has the basic formula:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N r^n = \frac{r^{N+1} - 1}{r-1}
$$
To apply this to your sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{50} e^{-0.123(n)}
$$
recognize that $e^{-0.123(n)} = (e^{-0.123})^n$ so your $r$ is $e^{-0.123}$.

Also your sum starts at $n=1$ while the formula starts the summation at $n=0$ so you need to adjust for this.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
S & = \sum_{n=1}^{50} e^{-0.123n} & & = \phantom{a_0 + {}} a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{49} + a_{50} \\[10pt]
\frac S {e^{-0.123}} & = \sum_{n=0}^{49} e^{-0.123n} & & = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{49} \\[10pt]
\end{align}
Subtracting the first row above from the second we get
$$
\frac S {e^{-0.123}} - S = a_0 - a_{50}.
$$
Therefore
$$
S\left( 1 - \frac 1 {e^{-0.123}} \right) = a_0 - a_{50}
$$
$$
S = \frac{a_0-a_{50}}{1 - \frac 1 {e^{-0.123}}} = \frac {1 - e^{-0.123(50)}}{1- \frac 1 {e^{-0.123}}}
$$

Comment: Hi @Michael, may I ask you for a further explanation, why there is $1 - \frac{1}{r}$ at final fraction's denominator, instead of $1-r$? When I tried this formula for a simple example; $N=3$, $r=2$, it yields a negative result (-14), instead of 14. Is it because 
$r$ value ($e^{-0.123}$) in your example is powered to a negative number? Thank you!